# Using a getJSON function to scrape webpage HTML I'm getting an error when trying to save the contents of the call to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript/JQuery to scrape some HTML off of a webpage. 
Here's the code I'm running:

```
var res = $.getJSON('http://api.allorigins.ml/get?url=https%3A//play.usaultimate.org/teams/events/Eventteam/%3FTeamId%3DDyfnwYxOk20EJ8z66rAnu8Vk%252fJ%252fHaEXYiIeBB7obkR0%253d&callback=?');
var data = res.responseJSON;
var htmlObject = $(data.contents);
```

typing this directly into the console works fine, however, when I attach this file as a script element onto an html file and open that file on my browser I'm getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined' response and the data and htmlObject variables are undefined.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong or if I'm doing anything wrong at all?

Comment: You need to provide `$.getJSON` a success function to access the `data`, as @Jack Bashford answers demonstrates. [$.getJSON manual](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the first line:

```
var res = $.getJSON('http://api.allorigins.ml/get?url=https%3A//play.usaultimate.org/teams/events/Eventteam/%3FTeamId%3DDyfnwYxOk20EJ8z66rAnu8Vk%252fJ%252fHaEXYiIeBB7obkR0%253d&callback=?');
```

You should see that by typing it into your console, you get `undefined`:

[image]

You need to do something with the data - here's how I rewrote your code to (hopefully) do what you want:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.allorigins.ml/get?url=https%3A//play.usaultimate.org/teams/events/Eventteam/%3FTeamId%3DDyfnwYxOk20EJ8z66rAnu8Vk%252fJ%252fHaEXYiIeBB7obkR0%253d&callback=?', function(data) {
    var response = data.responseJSON;
    var htmlObject = $(response.contents);
    console.log(htmlObject);
});
```